# Table with Jade iterating an array with error

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, pug

I'm new in node.js and Jade.

I searched for solutions without success, I want to create table rows in each loop in Jade.
This is the Jade template code:

```
 script(type='text/template', id='tmpl-results-table')
    table.table.table.table-striped
      thead
        tr
          th Meter N°
          th Reading
          th Date 
        tbody#results-rows

  script(type='text/template', id='tmpl-results-row')
      td <%= number %>

      |<%  _.each(data.list, function(item) {  %>
        td <%= item.last_reading %>
        td <%= item.last_date %>
    |<% }); %>
```

This is the backbone view results: `

```
{ data: 
   [ { _id: 513a21ad1de156331b000005,
       number: 12345678,
       list: 
        [ { last_reading: null,
            _id: 51c9b653bc14224c0a000006,
            last_date: Tue Jun 25 2013 17:25:07 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
          { last_reading: null,
            _id: 51c9b779025097990a000006,
            last_date: Tue Jun 25 2013 17:30:01 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
          { last_reading: 1234,
            _id: 51c9b78c025097990a000007,
            last_date: Tue Jun 25 2013 17:30:20 GMT+0200 (CEST) } ] } ],
  pages: 
   { current: 1,
     prev: 0,
     hasPrev: false,
     next: 0,
     hasNext: false,
     total: 1 },
  items: { begin: 1, end: 1, total: 1 } }
```

I want to render three objects on each row.But when i run my server and point my browser to it, i get foll error:

```
 33| 
    34|      |<% if (list.length) {  %>
  > 35|       |<% list.forEach(function(item) {  %>
    36|         
    37|         td <%= item.last_reading %>
    38|         td <%= item.last_date %>

unexpected token "indent"
```

I also use underscore.js with backbone